# Change location of chart using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to change the location of the graph that I generate with my vba. For now, it is just taking data from a column that may or may not change size. I understand I do not have 'Chart1' identified ion my code but I can not figure out where to declare it where it doesn't create another sheet for the chart as well.

```
reportsheet.Select
ActiveSheet.Range("a4", ActiveSheet.Range("a4").End(xlDown)).Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select

With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart1")
   .Left = Range("A40").Left
   .Top = Range("A40").Top
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change Name of active Chart and then assign the properties to it.

Try This...

```
    reportsheet.Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A4", ActiveSheet.Range("A4").End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select

    ActiveChart.Parent.Name = "Chart1"

    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart1")
       .Left = Range("A40").Left
       .Top = Range("A40").Top
    End With
```

Comment: Added that line to the VBA and it gave me a run time error that the item with the specified name wasn't found. It highlights the   With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart1") as the error line.

Answer (score 0):

I use make chart like this. Please refer to bellows.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet

    InsertCharts 20, Ws
    InsertCharts 30, Sheets("Sheet1")
End Sub

Sub InsertCharts(n As Integer, Ws As Worksheet)

    Dim Cht As Shape
    Dim t As Single, w As Integer, h As Integer, x As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    With Ws
        If .ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
            .ChartObjects.Delete
        End If

        x = 0
        t = .Range("a26").Top
        w = 217.1338582677
        h = 203.5275590551
        For i = 1 To n

                Set Cht = .Shapes.AddChart(, x, t, w, h)
            If i Mod 5 = 0 Then
                t = .Range("a26").Top
                x = x + w + 20
            Else
                t = t + h + 20
            End If

        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```